# Invite more than 300 friends to Facebook event via HTTP Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to invite all of a users friends to a Facebook event and so far I've found from Facebook the following:

> You can invite users to an event by issuing an HTTP POST to /EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID. You can invite multiple users by issuing an HTTP POST to /EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3

But I found this:

> You can invite an unlimited number of people to events, but you can only invite 100 people at a time. Once you invite the first 100 people, you can then start inviting more. In addition, you can only have 300 pending invites at one time for an event. Some people will have to respond to your event invite before you will be able to add more.

There are all sorts of javascript hacks to allow users to select all from the invite page on Facebook, but does anyone know how to invite more than 300 through the API's?

Comment: Did you test it? (I realize it's time consuming to create 300 test users though!) My *guess* is that the same restriction applies to the API as it does to the UI.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, mainly due to not wanting to invite all my random Facebook friends to a test event over and over, but then ran into the documentation before even trying. If anyone has experience that it does work, or that I could invite 300, then wait for confirmation, and invite another 300 etc. that would be great.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?? Still unsolved.